# angular не позволяет возвращать объект с функции

Tags: angularjs

Ошибка:

```
Error: $rootScope:infdig
Infinite $digest Loop
10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations: [[{"msg":"fn: function (c,e,f,g){f=d&&g?g[0]:a(c,e,f,g);return b(f,c,e)}","newVal":{"language":"ru","startDate":"2016-10-20T00:00:00.000Z","weekStart":1,"format":"dd-mm-yyyy","todayHighlight":true,"inline":true,"sideBySide":true},"oldVal":{"language":"ru","startDate":"2016-10-20T00:00:00.000Z","weekStart":1,"format":"dd-mm-yyyy","todayHighlight":true,"inline":true,"sideBySide":true}}],
```

Как решить эту проблему, чего я еще не понимаю ?
Есть такой шаблон для теста

```
<div id="datepicker50" ng-datepicker
                     dp-options="discount.dpConfigInitDate('2016-10-20')"
                     ng-model="discount.date"></div>
```

Метод с контроллера

```
vm.dpConfigInitDate = dpConfigInitDate;

    function dpConfigInitDate(date) {
        return DatePickerConfig('inline', new Date(date));
    }
```

DatePickerConfig

```
function DatePickerConfig (type, withInitDate) {

    var _date = null;

    if (withInitDate instanceof Date) {
        _date = withInitDate;
    } else if (!withInitDate) {
        _date = new Date();
    } else {
        _date = getDate();
    }

    var config = {
        language: Loc.getLang(),
        startDate: _date,
        weekStart: 1,
        format: 'dd-mm-yyyy',
        todayHighlight: true
    };

    switch (type) {
        case 'default':
            return config;
            break;
        case 'inline':
            angular.extend(config, {
                inline: true,
                sideBySide: true
            });

            return config;
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: суть в том, как отслеживается этот атрибут. Так как в директиве указано `=`, на каждом digest цикле идет проверка, что значение этого атрибута не поменялось, но из-за того, что каждый раз возвращается новый объект - ангуляр думает, что значение изменилось и запускает digest цикл еще раз, и повторят до тех пор, пока значение не будет меняться, либо пока не будет превышен лимит, в данном случае: `10 $digest() iterations reached`

Comment: Есть ли способ исправить ситуацию ?

Comment: можно возвращать всегда один и тот же объект. Ну и не совсем понятно: в чем вообще смысл этой функции и зачем ее вызывать несколько раз

Comment: Она вызывается только один раз, и я не могу возвращать один и тот же объект так как дату нужно инициализаровать

Comment: как я сказал выше: данная функция вызывается на каждый digest цикл